# Convert exception with bactrace to string in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a function in Julia I want to call for a set of arguments. It might throw an exeption and i want to convert it to a string with bactrace and log it for further examination.

```
for i in 1:100
    try
        myfun(i)
    catch ex
        println(ex)
        println(bactrace(ex)) # does not work
    end
end
```

How can one do this in Julia?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit old question, but here's what I found:

```
Base.show_backtrace(io, bt)
```

shows just the backtrace, and

```
sprint(io->Base.show_backtrace(io, bt))
```

prints it into a string in case you want to log it.

Edit: error_show in the previous answer is showerror now; it seems

```
str = showerror(STDOUT, ex, catch_backtrace())
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/S485_5jG2Nw

Update 2: In v0.5 you can just do `stacktrace()` and `catch_stacktrace()`

Although you'd have to loop through the array of stacktraces to print it AFAIK.

Source: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/stacktraces/

Answer (score 1):

A litle more searching in the code found that this kind of works. It uses a function not exported in the API so it might break in the future, but for now it prints me a stack trace.

```
try
    function()
catch ex
    Base.error_show(STDERR, ex, catch_backtrace())
end
```